# How to get child value of div seperately using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a div tag which contains three anchor tags and have url in them.
I am able to print those 3 hrefs but they get merged into one value.
Is there a way I can get three seperate values.

Div looks like this:

```
<div class="speaker_social_wrap">
<a href="https://twitter.com/Sigve_telenor" target="_blank">
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="x-icon x-icon-twitter" data-x-icon-b=""></i>
</a>
<a href="https://no.linkedin.com/in/sigvebrekke" target="_blank">
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="x-icon x-icon-linkedin-in" data-x-icon-b=""></i>
</a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sigve.telenor" target="_blank">
<i aria-hidden="true" class="x-icon x-icon-facebook-f" data-x-icon-b=""></i>
</a>
```

What I have tried so far:

```
social_media_url = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'foo')
  for url in social_media_url:
    print(url)
```

Expected Result:

```
http://twitter-url
http://linkedin-url
http://facebook-url
```

My Output

```
<div><a twitter-url><a linkedin-url><a facebook-url></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://dtw.tmforum.org/speakers/sigve-brekke-2/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
a = soup.find('div', class_='speaker_social_wrap').find_all('a')
for i in a:
    print(i['href'])
```

```
https://twitter.com/Sigve_telenor
https://no.linkedin.com/in/sigvebrekke
https://www.facebook.com/sigve.telenor
```

Comment: Corrected my html..can you check once again

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' Getting this error

Comment: If your HTML code is different, then you will obviously get that error. Did you copy my answer and ran it ? Did you get any such error then ?

Comment: It would be better if you post the exact HTML code you have or the URL @RaspberryLemon

Comment: https://dtw.tmforum.org/speakers/sigve-brekke-2/ I am trying to extract the social media urls

Comment: @RaspberryLemon Updated the answer accordingly. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Your selector gives you the `div` not the urls array. You need something more like:

```
social_media_div = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'foo')
social_media_anchors = social_media_div.find_all('a')
for anchor in social_media_anchors:
  print(anchor.get('href'))
```